# Access to phpMyAdmin failed in Xampp: invalid settings

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to connect to phpmyadmin and one error always stops the process no matter how many changes I make in settings of Xampp and that's:  **invalid settings error. phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.**
I tried everything I saw on the internet and YouTube, but still have the problem.
I really apreciate it if you give a solution for this.

[screenshot from the error in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7gh3.png)

Here is my **config.inc.php** file settings:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

**Note:** Apache and Mysql ports are ok and they work just fine

Apache: 447, 8080 /
Mysql: 3307

Comment: We cannot tell you what the right connection parameters are, this is something you need to know!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

To

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Because you are using no password and configuring your server that, deny services without password

Comment: I've done that before @Gamer In The Game, I've changed it from false to true but still the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure that MySQL user is 'root' and password is ''. The error says that only that information is not true. Maybe you can try re-install the Xampp.

Comment: Yes I reinstalled it , but nothing happened and I haven't created any sql database so there isn't any password to enter, And user 'root', is the default value it had at first without any password. @Gamer In The Game